# VNC client(only) in Ubuntu 18.04 headless server

Tags: 18.04, kvm-virtualization, vnc, client, headless

So basically I'm trying to setup a configuration line Qubes os but based on Ubuntu and KVM. I used Ubuntu 18.04 but it's still too heavy and I'm thinking of using headless Ubuntu for KVM installation. But problem is, most guides out there on the subject assumes setup on 2 different machines, one for server and one with VNC client to access VMs. What I want to do is to install VNC client right into headless Ubuntu server, preferably without installing any desktop env(and very minimal one if I have to). Any suggestions please?

Comment: If you want a server, install a server distro, no need for a graphical UI. Connect to it through SSH like Christian says. VNC requires too much resources.

Answer (score 0):

you can install only `libvirt-daemon-system` on the server which will not pull in any UI components.

I'd assume you already have a SSH key based setup to reach your server, if not I'd set one up before the next step.

On the client install virt-manager - if you want even without recommends (as you don't want to virtualize on the client).

You now can connect the libvirt on the server as a `remote` via the menu "File -> Add Connection".

You can now either use virt-manager to install from an ISO, or use any other commandline tool on the server to create your initial guest. Later on you can start/stop/view that remote guest from `virt-manager` as needed.

I quickly checked, and while a bit dated [this doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/VirtManager) seems to cover the basics still.